# Beginner to SML / NJ. How to find largest Value in list

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

> We want to find the largest value in a given nonempty list of integers.  Then we have to compare elements in the list. Since data
>   values are given as  a sequence, we can do comparisons from the
>   beginning or from the end of  the list. Define in both ways. a)
>   comparison from the beginning b) comparison from the end  (How can we
>   do this when data values are in a list?) No auxiliary functions.

I've been playing around a lot with recursive functions, but can't seem to figure out how to compare two values in the list.

```
fun listCompare [] = 0
  | listCompare [x] = x
  | listCompare (x::xs) = listCompare(xs)
```

This will break the list down to the last element, but how do I start comparing and composing the list back up?

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the first two elements of a given list and keep the larger element in the list and drop the other. Once the list has only one element, then you have the maximum. In functional pseudocode for a) it looks roughly like so:

```
lmax []  = error "empty list"
lmax [x] = x
lmax (x::y::xs) = 
  if x > y then lmax (x::xs)
  else          lmax (y::xs)
```

For b) you could reverse the list first.

Comment: Thank you! When trying to run it, I get a Syntax error that says "Inserting ORELSE".

Comment: As mentioned in the answer I didn't use SML syntax to illustrate the algorithm, as it looks like homework and you should familiasires yourself with the language constructs. you need to define the function using `fun` and if syntax is as follows: `fun f args = if ... then ... else ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `foldl` (or `foldr`) function in the [SML list library](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html) is for :

```
foldl : ((`a * `b) -> `b) -> `b -> `a list -> `b
```

You can simply add an anonymous function to compare the current element against the accumulator :

```
fun lMax l =
    foldl (fn (x,y) => if x > y then x else y) (nth l 0) l
```

The `nth` function simply takes the `int list : l` and an `int : 0` to return the first element in the list. As lists in SML are written recursively as : `h :: t`, retrieving the first element is an `O(1)` operation, and using the `foldl` function greatly increases the elegance of code. The whole point of having a functional language is to define abstractions to pass around anonymous functions as higher-order functions and re-use the abstract type definitions with concrete functions.